# A word descibing an object specifically designed to hold the shape or form of something else

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe a general class of objects which are specifically designed to hold the form or shape of another object.

Almost the opposite or inverse of a mould. In a similar way that a skeleton holds the shape of a body, or a cobbler's iron holds the shape of a shoe while being worked upon.

I'm thinking of something in a similar vein to a brace, frame, scaffold, or a jig. Specifically a solid object inside of another object that would not hold its form otherwise.

---

The context in which I wish to use this word:

"The coil is wound and bound tightly to the plastic `word`, in order that the coil maintains it shape and form"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest the word **former**:

> The coil is wound and bound tightly to the plastic **former**, in order that the coil maintains it shape and form.

The [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/former) entry says

> **former**
>   NOUN
>
> **1.1** A tool, mould, or other device used to form articles or shape materials.
>
> *The sheets are drawn over shaped formers to the extent that they deform plastically and assume the required profiles.*

Comment: I think you win a coconut!

Comment: Or just *form*.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede that is more like a mould: for example **formwork** to contain concrete, but OP wants the opposite.

Comment: @WeatherVane The word *form* doesn't suggest positive or negative to me (AmE). And the second definition you quoted contains the word *mould*.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede that's a fair observation, I suggest you write an answer.

Comment: That would be redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Armature, in the arts.  It's the second definition in most dictionaries, but wire as armature is quite common.

[Armature](https://www.lexico.com/definition/armature)

> 2. An open framework on which a sculpture is moulded with clay or similar material.
>
> > We do build twisted aluminium wire armatures (skeleton-like structures
> >     that the model can be built around) which are used for models with
> >     simple or limited movement.
>
> 2.1 A framework or formal structure, especially of a literary work.
>
> > Shakespeare's plots have served as the armature for many novels.

Comment: I really like this word! I hadn't come across it. It doesn't feel quite right for my purpose, but +1 because you taught me something new.

Answer (score 1):

Scaffold is what came to mind while going through your question, then i read that you are already look for a word similar to that.

What about

> Skeleton

Also may I know in what context you intend to use this?

Comment: Yes skeleton also came to mind, but specifically one solid object. I'll add the conext to the question.

Comment: What about 'frame'?

Comment: Might be a bit far-fetched but what about 'core'?